# Does the arithmetic operation of signed and unsigned int cause the loss of accuracy?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

According to C99_standard's 6.3.1.8:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type.

So for the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    int32_t s, s1 = -1;
    uint32_t u1 = 1;
    s = s1 + u1;
    printf("s-->%d", s); // prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

For the code line `s = s1 + u1`, it would follow these steps:

- Step 1: convert `s1` from `int32_t` to `uint32_t`;
- Step 2: do the addition and yield an `uint32_t` result;
- Step 3: convert the `uint32_t` result to `int32_t` that is consistent with the type of `s`.

Does the operation of `int32_t` and `uint32_t` cause the loss of accuracy?

If so, could someone give an example?

Comment: @KamilCuk: Accuracy means fidelity to a correct value. A result that is incorrect is inaccurate, even if the cause is overflow rather than rounding.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by loss of accuracy? And do you care about C standard specifics, or just what behavior typical implementations will have?

Comment: When `int` is 32 bits and `1u - 2` is evaluated, the result is 4,294,967,295, but the real-number arithmetic result of 1−2 is −1. Is that the sort of loss of accuracy you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `int` is 32 bits wide with 2's complement representation so that `int` can represent all values of `int32_t` but `int` cannot represent all values of `uint32_t`, then in the expression statement `s = s1 + u1;`, the following evaluations are performed:

1. `s1` and `u1` are converted to their respective value and type:

   ```
   s = s1 + u1;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (int32_t)(-1) + (uint32_t)1;
   ```
2. `int32_t` is promoted to `int` and `uint32_t` is promoted to `unsigned int` (see previous assumptions):

   ```
   s = (int32_t)(-1) + (uint32_t)1;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (int)(int32_t)(-1) + (unsigned int)(uint32_t)1;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (int)(-1) + (unsigned int)1;
   ```
3. `int` is converted to `unsigned int`:

   ```
   s = (int)(-1) + (unsigned int)1;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (unsigned int)(int)(-1) + (unsigned int)1;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (unsigned int)4294967295 + (unsigned int)1;
   ```

   (Note: assumed `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295u`.) The negative value has been converted to `unsigned int` by adding 4294967296 to bring it into range.
4. The addition of the `unsigned int` values is performed:

   ```
   s = (unsigned int)4294967295 + (unsigned int)1;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (unsigned int)0;
   ```

   (Note: assumed `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295u`.) The mathematical result of the addition 4294967295+1 = 4294967296 has been reduced modulo 4294967296 to 0 to bring it into range of `unsigned int`.
5. The result of the addition is converted to `int32_t`:

   ```
   s = (unsigned int)0;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (int32_t)(unsigned int)0;
   ```

   →

   ```
   s = (int32_t)0;
   ```

"Loss of accuracy" occurred when -1 was converted to 4294967295 and when 4294967296 was converted to 0, but they cancelled each other out to produce the correct mathematical result -1 + 1 = 0. There was no undefined behavior during the evaluation.

If the result of the addition of `unsigned int` values and reduction modulo UINT_MAX+1 happened to be greater than `INT32_MAX` then the result of conversion to `int32_t` would be implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal would be raised. (However, in practice, most implementations do not raise a signal and just truncate or sign-extend the bit pattern to the desired width.)

Answer (score 0):

1. It can lead to undefined behaviour (UB) if the result will not fit into the *signed* integer result. Is UB an inaccuracy? I do not know.
2. If the result variable is unsigned and the result cant be accommodated into it, then it will `wraparound` and the result will be different from the "normal math one" but well defined - thus IMO "accurate"